# Expanding a NuGet Package (nupkg) From the Command-Line

Tags: nuget

I have access to the NuGet command-line tool but not to any unzip tools. Is it possible to install a package already saved locally?

After doing a number of searches, I've come up with nothing that handles such a simple requirement. I've also looked at the code but it's far too lengthy/dense to quickly come to a definite conclusion, though, by all indications, it *doesn't* support the direct install of a local file.

Comment: If powershell 5 is installed, you can use `expand-archive`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, though this environment doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the .nupkg stored locally in a directory and all you want to do is extract the files you could use NuGet.exe and do something like:

```
NuGet.exe install -o extract-directory MyPackageId -source /Full/Path/To/Directory/Containing/NuGet/Package/NuPkgs
```

The -source parameter allows you to define a new source. In this case the directory where the .nupkg file exists.

The -o parameter defines the directory where you want the NuGet package extracted to.

The above seems to work on the Mac with NuGet 2.12.

Comment: It is a hack, but this might also satisfy the requirement and is also clever. Can I control where this information gets recorded so that I can compartmentalize it to the current process? In other words, if the process somehow crashes and doesn't cleanup properly can I configure the source in such a way that it's not a global change that might affect all NuGet-commamd lists/installs/etc..?

Comment: I am just wondering if you could create a local NuGet.Config file with the package source that points to the directory so nothing global is changed. In theory NuGet.exe should just find that NuGet.Config file and use it. So you would not need to use nuget sources at all. That would be cleaner.

Comment: There is an even simpler way. I have updated the answer.

Comment: It's weird that I previously tried to do an install using that method and it didn't work. However, I just did it for "list" and it worked exactly as expected. Thanks for revisiting that option with me, Matt.

Comment: The secondary problem with this, though, is that it prevents a private repository from being used. If any of the dependencies of your package can't be resolved against the directory that you're using for your source then the tool will fallback to using the public one. It won't let you provide more than one source (which is not unexpected). You either need to deposit all of your packages and their dependencies into the same directory or provide a config file that enumerates *all* of the directories/servers that host them. Building a config is out of scope for the release process for me though.

Answer (score 5):

Since it's really just a zip file.

```
mv ~/path/to/package.nupkg package.zip
```

This will change the file extension to be a zip file. Then:

```
unzip package.zip -d ~/Output/dir
```

Comment: For some reason, if I renamed the file in "Finder" to a my.zip, but tried to open it by a double click, it failed.  But this worked.